# Why can't I access the body or properties of this POST request sent to a HTTP Firebase Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm sending a `POST` request to a HTTP Firebase Cloud Function endpoint which contains the following body:

```JSON
{
  "securityContext": "edbsne0f17660e9ab49ad9bc3ddd4656230e0a9304bd15916f595b793da9109e1f7aa61e76c4afa91319011a7259b24ed583302334e22c5544c4e00506cf2fed93b28434e4088b22dda02712adf63bb6a370f",
  "event": "onInstall",
  "orgId": "7001935574",
  "dc": "AU"
}
```

But when I try to access any of those properties it shows `undefined`. The entire body is also `undefined`.

This is what my `onRequest` HTTP Cloud Function endpoint looks like. It also shows my other failed attempts of getting the body data, which I have commented out:

```TypeScript
export const getZohoDeskCallBack = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  const body = req.body;
  functions.logger.info('body', body);

  const rawBody = req.body;
  functions.logger.info('rawBody', rawBody);

  // Other attempt 1:
  // const bodySecurityContext = req.body.securityContext;
  // functions.logger.info('bodySecurityContext', bodySecurityContext);

  // Other attempt 2:
  // const rawBodySecurityContext = req.rawBody.securityContext;
  // functions.logger.info('rawBodySecurityContext', rawBodySecurityContext);

  // Other attempt 3:
  // const reqBodyToJSON = req.body.toJSON();
  // functions.logger.info('req.body.toJSON()', reqBodyToJSON);

  // Other attempt 4:
  // const reqRawBodyToJSON = req.rawBody.toJSON();
  // functions.logger.info('req.rawBody.toJSON()', reqRawBodyToJSON);

  // Other attempt 5:
  // const reqBodyToJSONparse = JSON.parse(req.body);
  // functions.logger.info('reqBodyToJSONparse', reqBodyToJSONparse);

  // Other attempt 6:
  // const reqRawBodyToJSONparse = JSON.parse(req.rawBody);
  // functions.logger.info('reqRawBodyToJSONparse', reqRawBodyToJSONparse);

  // Other attempt 7:
  // const reqBodyToJSONparse = req.body.toString();
  // functions.logger.info('reqBodyToJSONparse', reqBodyToJSONparse);

  // Other attempt 8:
  // const reqRawBodyToJSONparse = req.rawBody.toString();
  // functions.logger.info('reqRawBodyToJSONparse', reqRawBodyToJSONparse);

  // Other attempt 9:
  // const reqBodyToJSONparse = req.body.toString();
  // const securityContext = reqBodyToJSONparse.securityContext;
  // functions.logger.info('securityContext', securityContext);

  res.end();
});
```

**You can see a test of the `POST` request [here](https://webhook.site/#!/1c45a8ce-4b2f-4f33-a09e-3376dfb36dd8/5cd970a6-69b0-4a6f-9860-c23a87e08925/1) and [here](https://hookbin.com/JKd7ynPaVOcg1WBgV29M).**

Apparently, if a request has a `content-type` of `application/json` Firebase Cloud Functions will automatically parse the JSON and put it into the `body` property.

But as you can see from those tests linked above the header `content-type` is empty or missing. Also I am **unable to change the `POST` request** because I have no control over that.

Maybe that could be the issue? If so, I thought I could access it from the `rawBody` property, but that also doesn't work.

I have been pulling my hair out trying to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show on front how you are calling this function?

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans the call is coming from a 3rd party service. So I do not have the front end code for how the function is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apparently, if a request has a content-type of application/json Firebase Cloud Functions will automatically parse the JSON and put it into the body property.

That's because you do need to add the `Content-Type` header and Firebase use the appropriate parser for that request. For more information on the libraries that Firebase uses, checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request).

You can use the body parser middleware and force [parse the body as JSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions:%7E:text=to%20true.-,type,-The%20type%20option) as shown below:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions/v1";
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";

const app = express();

const parseJsonMiddleware = bodyParser.json({
  type(req) {
    return true;
  },
});

app.post("/getZohoDeskCallBack", parseJsonMiddleware, (req, res) => {
  const body = req.body;
  console.log("body", body);

  const rawBody = req.body;
  console.log("rawBody", rawBody);

  res.end();
});

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

You'll have to update your webhook URL as this will add `/api` in the URL like this:

```
POST https://[FUNCTIONS_URL]/api/getZohoDeskCallBack
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm using TypeScript, and `type(req)` inside `parseJsonMiddleware` is giving me the error: `'req' is declared but its value is never read. ts(6133)`. What exactly does this part do? And how to solve that error?

Comment: Adding to the above comment, I know from reading the body-parser docs that the `type` option is used to determine what media type the middleware will parse. But I don't understand how it is used in your code, or how to avoid the TypeScript error.

Comment: @TinyTiger that `type` can be a function as in my answer. From the docs, ". If a function, the type option is called as fn(req) and the request is parsed if it returns a truthy value.". We are always returning true so it'll always parse the body as JSON. For the TS issues, can you just remove the `req` parameter from the function and try? If that doesn't work try using `//@ts-ignore` for that line once.